# Is $a_n \geq 0$ for this question?

Tags: calculus, summation

So a series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ has n$^{th}$ partial sum $s_n = \dfrac{2^n-3}{2^n}$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. From this information is $a_n \geq 0$ and is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=1$. Personally I just have the information of partial sum, that is all i know. Then I know very fast $a_n \not \geq0$, because the first term, $s_1$ is negative.

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=1$, I don't know how I can prove that or show it's fake. But if I compute limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{2^n-3}{2^n}=1$, so I think that's where it came from. But it's not true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right; $a_1=s_1=-1/2<0$ is negative. Do note that as $s_n$ is an increasing sequence, $a_n\geq 0$ for $n\geq 2.$

You are also right to say that $\sum a_n=1$ as by defintion of a series sum, $\sum a_n=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} s_n=1.$